# Sharepoint apps configuration with SAN certs?

Tags: sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app, provider-hosted-app, certificate

In our current environment, our app environment is configured with wild card using verisign certs. As Google is planning to mistrusting all certs  issued by Symantec and in which verisign falls under its umbrella. We are planning to get away from it.

We are currently looking for an alternative and I didnt find much info on using SAN certs. Does wildcard cert is only cert that we can use for app configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why wildcard certs are all but required for the App Domain is that the identifier of the App is generated at installation time of the App. So an App installed on one Site Collection will have a different identifier from an App installed in another Site Collection.

Since you cannot predict the URLs, and you'd have to re-issue a cert each time you deployed an App, a wildcard is a must.

Comment: Thank you Trevor, Im big fan of your books. Thanks for taking your time to respond to my question.

Comment: Thanks! Here's more info by the way - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161236.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Create%20a%20new%20wildcard%20SSL%20certificate

Comment: @user6119395 Please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted in case it helped you!